# Display External Jobs using XML feeds in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part

How can I show the external jobs provided in XML feeds on Sharepoint 2013?

My initial research suggests creating a webpart with XML viewer feature.
Add the required XML file link and XSL information.

It shows the data from XML feeds, but in an unstructured format.

Please help to understand how to make it show only the specific Jobs link on the webpart and allow user to click on it to view overall.

Answer (score 0):

`XML` with `XSLT` applied gives a simple `HTML`. Use any tool to compose XSLT (I'd recommend Altova's), then follow the steps of ['*Use the XML Viewer Web Part...*' at support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-XML-Viewer-Web-Part-to-display-structured-data-and-XML-based-documents-and-forms-00d6ed40-bd73-4754-b869-0477a034bcfd). In XSLT you'll use XPath to filter elements.

Hope this helps - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp

Comment: Aziz, tanks for your comments. any clue how to show data XSLT format as its supported by SPS 2013?

Comment: Hi @Jason. I'm not sure I got you right. XSLT is a transformation language, like CSS for HTML. Do you need help with writing XLST for your XML?

Comment: Hi Aziz,

Yes i need help in writing XLST, as need to add few HTML tags in between.

Exampple:

Title (to be fetch from XML by XSLT ) "-"  "[" Description (to be fetch from XML by XSLT ) "]"